# ajax http request without form reload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am having problem with form onsubmit().
I do not want to reload page and only want to pass 2 parameter to another php.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function doSomething() {

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("addCategory").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","/api/add_item_main_category.php?q1="+document.getElementById("myText1").value+"&q2="+document.getElementById("myText2").value,false); ///* Tested with true */
    xmlhttp.send();
    return false;
  }
  </script>
```

Here is my Form.

```
<form href="JavaScript:void(0);" onsubmit="return doSomething(); ">
    <input type="text" id="myText1" name="maincategory" placeholder="Main Category" style="width: 100%;">
    <input type="text" id="myText2" name="subcategory" placeholder="Sub Category" style="width: 100%;">
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Main Category">
    <br/>
    <div id="addCategory" ></div> 
</form>
```

Submit button works on like this url `"/api/add_item_main_category.php?q1=Car&q2=Toyota"`. Not working with user input just like above form and it redirected.

Comment: Try using preventDefault(). > Cancel the event. `doSomething(e) { e.preventDefault(); [...Rest of your code...] }` [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in browser console? Also a form has no `href`

Comment: You can use jQuery.submit() event in your form and make Ajax request in onsubmit jQuery handler. And - yes - use preventDefault() in order to prevent form reload when submitting

Comment: Added e.preventDefault();. But it still redirecting. Thank you. @Robiseb

Comment: There is no error just redirect. Do you think it'll be form error in one of answer @charlietfl . Thank you so much. [Honestly I don't know how to  catch console error]

Comment: I forgot to tell you, put the `return false;` line outside of the `if` statement, at the end of the `doSomething()` function. So `doSomething(e) { e.preventDefault(); [...Rest of your code...]; return false; }`

Comment: e.preventDefault(); working now . Not redirected. But not passing input data just it is zero. Thank you so much all . So much easier for me . Thank you .

Comment: Use type="button" and add on click event on it instead of using form submit. On click event send ajax. It will not reload.